# Return control of the screen orientation to the device

Tags: android, default, device-orientation

I'm trying to build an app that is always set to landscape mode and since i don't have any activities in my application, i tried to change the orientation of my application by changing the device's orientation.
This worked well for my application, but since i'm controlling the whole device's orientation, some places were affected by my code for eg.(on my device the homescreen had never rotated, but when i added my code to the application it started rotating to landscape)

so what i want to ask is (after i closed my app) how can i make the device's orientation work as it usually did before adding my own code?

here is my code:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Service.WINDOW_SERVICE);

    orientationChanger = new LinearLayout(this);
    orientationChanger.setClickable(false);
    orientationChanger.setFocusable(false);
    orientationChanger.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    orientationChanger.setLongClickable(false);

    LayoutParams orientationLayout = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);

    wm.addView(orientationChanger, orientationLayout);
    orientationChanger.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    orientationLayout.screenOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
    wm.updateViewLayout(orientationChanger, orientationLayout);
    orientationChanger.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is complete overkill. Just use the `screenOrientation` attribute for your `Activity` tags in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape">
```

Comment: I don't have activities in my app ! I'm trying to work with android services specially `InputMethodService`, and that's why i'm controlling the whole device's orientation

Comment: I'm confused, I guess. If you don't have any UI, why do you need to control orientation?

Comment: No I have a class that extends Relative layout and i customize it in a `main.xml` file, then in my `InputMethodService` class i call it:

`getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main, null);`

Comment: So you're trying to make an input method, and you want to force any app that uses your input method into landscape?

Comment: I want to force the InputMethod itself to be into landscape every time it shows up

Comment: Which will also require the application using they input method to be in landscape.

Comment: Actually, my `InputMethod` should be used as the default keyboard of the device. so it will be used by every application on the device that needs text entry functionality.
I don't know if i can control every application that uses my `InputMethod` to be in landscape mode only when the `InputMethod` shows up .. Is that possible ?